# abas ERP FOP "menue command" with multiple rows

Tags: erp, abas

I want to create a dynamic menu with multiple rows unfortunately **I have no success in formatting my rows one below the other.**

Abas onlinehelp shows the option - to align the rows to the left and + to align the row to the right, but these options have no effect.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
..!interpreter english noabbrev
..
.type int  xii1
.type int  xii2
.type int  xii3
.type int  xii4
.type text xtmenu
..
.formula U|xii1 = 0
.file -TEMPNAME U|xtmenu
.input DATEI.F
.output NEW 'U|xtmenu
..
..: Create a dynamic menue
..
'G|kommandochar'menu
 -         +         -         -
..
!LOOP
.continue LOOPEND ? U|xii1 >= 100
.formula U|xii1 = U|xii1 + 5
.formula U|xii2 = U|xii1 + 5
.formula U|xii3 = U|xii2 + 5
.formula U|xii4 = U|xii3 + 5
'U|xii1 ' ' U|xii2' 'U|xii3 ' 'U|xii4 '
.continue LOOP
!LOOPEND
..
.output TERMINAL
..
..: call dynamic menue
.input 'U|xtmenu'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
'G|kommandochar'menu
-         +         -         +
First     Second    Third     Fourth
..
!LOOP
.continue LOOPEND ? U|xii1 >= 100
.formula U|xii1 = U|xii1 + 5
.formula U|xii2 = U|xii1 + 5
.formula U|xii3 = U|xii2 + 5
.formula U|xii4 = U|xii3 + 5
'U|xii1 ' 'U|xii2 ' 'U|xii3 ' 'U|xii4 '
```

All the variables have to have fixed widths applied in the same direction.

Comment: "All the variables have to have fixed widths applied in the _same direction_" that was exact the problem :-). I thought I have to format right aligned values by using spaces before the variable. THX and welcome by stackoverflow!